# Math - PHP + MySQL add values and output

Tags: php, mysql, math

I am looking for a way to count multiple fields for a spending tracking app

So for example Transportation (Gas, Car) =>

Table Transportation

- Record_ID - Record_CAT - Record_SUM
- 1 -1 - 450.23
- 2 -1 - 124.12
- 3 -1 - 45.02

What I want to do is when user goes to ?view=1 (Record_CAT = 1) => Transportation query is ran and all records from Transportation table are fetched and displayed into a table on the page.

And the have the php count the Record_SUM and provide Final_SUM of XXXX used up on Transportation cost.

How would I need to do such query?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT record_id, record_cat, record_sum, SUM(record_sum) as final_sum FROM `transportation_table` Where record_cat=1
```

This should work